# How do I get the value of the "a" tags from Redmine?

Tags: javascript, html

Need to get the value of the "a" tags from Redmine (application numbers)
The problem is that it has to get the value from the tag and compare it with another value on another site in order to display a notification. Everything is done through a browser extension (Chrome).

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `document.querySelector(".id a").innerText;`?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I need to send the data that Redmine outputs to another site through the extension, where it will compare the values received.

Comment: Your question is about getting the number; posting it to the other site is a different issue entirely and would probably be too specific to meet the question requirements of Stackoverflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.